# UIKit importing in Struct definition

Tags: xcode, swift, uikit, ios9.3

While adding UIKit module in Struct definition through Xcode7.3.
I get red line on UIKit (it feels as deprecated) as show in Image below , What does it mean?

[image: UIkit in Xcode]